# Download html in JS and send to server side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to send a JSON string from the server side to the client with URL's.

The client should then through JavaScript/JQuery download the HTML files and send the content back to the server side.

This should happen without the user need to interact.

Is that possible with JavaScript/JQuery to get the client to download html and then send it to the server side?

**Update**

The purpose is to get the client to download the html rather than the server.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/";
var serverurl = "http://myserverurl/handler";
jQuery.get(url, "", function(data, status){
  jQuery.post(serverurl, jQuery.param({source: data}), function(data2, status2){
  }, "json");
}, "html");
```

That might do what you need: make the `url` and `serverurl` variables the right values.

EDIT: note that you'll get SOME source, but for anything other than the most trivial page implementation you will only get the page HTML source, but no media or css files or dynamically loaded resources.

EDIT: as @Rocket correctly pointed out, Same-Origin restrictions do apply. This will only work if you are accessing a server with the appropriate [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) setup.

Comment: It would be a great if the server side also could ask the client to download the images after it have received the html. Can binary data be send over in a similar manner?

Comment: The big issue is correctly parsing out from the HTML the images that need to be fetched: it would be somewhat complex but you could on the server side extract all the image links and then send back in the JSON response the list of images to be fetched. Pulling those images on the client and then sending them to the server is a good bit more complex, though.

Comment: How does this even work?  `$.get` can't just download arbitrary URLs, that violates the Same-Origin Policy.